# How to avoid the setState() / render() endless loop when passing data from child to parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to save child-data in the state of the parent, but end up with the endless loop because `setState()` calls `render()`.

**Error message:** Maximum update depth exceeded.This can happen when a component repeatedly calls `setState` inside `componentWillUpdate` or `componentDidUpdate`. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Relatively new to React, so I can't seem to word the question when googling solutions. I know why the error is occurring, I just don't know how to get around the issue. Is there a specific method I can use that prevents re-rendering?

Here is the parent:

```
export class ToDoList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: null
    }
  }

  myCallback = (dataFromChild) => {
    this.setState({data: dataFromChild.toUpperCase()})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ToDoItem callbackFromParent={this.myCallback}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The child:

```
class ToDoItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      listInfo: 'Doggos'
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <h1>{this.props.callbackFromParent(this.state.listInfo)}</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? There are a lot of problems with this code.

Comment: Why are you even calling that callback? Just show the `listInfo` in that `<h1>` tag and be done with it.

Comment: Not just `componentWillUpdate` and `componentDidUpdate` should not call `setState`, but also `render` should not cause a state change.

Comment: Your code is doing exactly what you told it to do. Every time it renders, it sets the state. This is an anti-pattern. Until you clarify what you are wanting it to do, it cannot be determined how best to fix it. Should the state update every render? What is actually supposed to be displayed? From reading your code, it appears that what you want it to do is what you described: loop infinitely.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda Ultimately I want to be able to share data between siblings and I am trying to do that by giving the data to the parent as the middleman. Sorry that wasn't clear, I was just testing a bit of code to see data-flow so this snippet is not actually supposed to do anything useful. It should just be rendering the data with capital letters (just to see if the data has passed through parent)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is doing exactly that, an endless loop. When your `ToDoItem` component renders, it calls `callbackFromParent` which updates the state of `ToDoList`, causing `ToDoList` to re-render, subsequently re-rendering the `ToDoItem`. Since `ToDoItem` re-renders, it calls `callbackFromParent` again and so on...

I'd like to ask why you are trying to render the non-value-returning function of `callbackFromParent`. It doesn't return anything, so it doesn't make sense why you'd want to render it inside of your `<h1>` tags.

Comment: I guess this isn't a very useful piece of code (just testing data flow between components), but basically I'm trying to save it in the parent-state so that I can then use the data in a different child-component. Sharing data between siblings

Comment: @Jen typically in React, we try to keep the state in the parent only, and then pass parts of the state to the children. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small problem with the code you shared, that you are calling a function from the `render()` rather than binding it to some event which is making it go into infinite loop...

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```js
class ToDoList extends React.Component {

  toUpper = (dataFromChild) => {
    return dataFromChild.toUpperCase();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ToDoItem toUpper={this.toUpper}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ToDoItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      listInfo: 'Doggos'
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <h1>{this.props.toUpper(this.state.listInfo)}</h1>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ToDoList />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

You are getting an endless loop because of the following reasons:

1) You are calling the parent callback on each render.

2) You are saving the uppercased value in the parent state.

When the parent state gets updated, the child gets re-rendered, meaning that it will call the callback again, which will cause to re-render, which calls the callback again etc...

An alternative solution would be to pass the util function down to the child which can then call it **once** when it re-renders. Since no state in the parent is being updated, the child will not be re-rendered.

Comment: This is using a parent component's method as transformation, it's not storing data in parent and visualizing it in child as OP asked for "I am trying to save child-data in the state of the parent", see first line in question

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to save data on parent but want to display it in child, try this:

Here is the parent:

```
export class ToDoList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: null
    }
  }

  myCallback = (dataFromChild) => {
    this.setState({data: dataFromChild})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ToDoItem callbackFromParent={this.myCallback} data={this.state.data}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The child:

```
class ToDoItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      times: 0
    }
    // Bind Explained below
    this.iBeClicked = this.iBeClicked.bind(this);
  }

  iBeClicked(){
    this.setState({times: ++this.props.data});
    this.props.callbackFromParent(this.props.data++);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="wrap">
        <h1 onClick="iBeClicked">{this.props.data !== null ? this.props.data: 'Nothing' }</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You use this.method.bind(this) in order to bind Component's this to React callback's execution inside render.

Comment: Why add the click event?

Comment: Because it's uncertain of what he's trying to achieve besides passing from child to parent. What you're proposing @ChaseDeAnda is a parent component transform, you're using parent's callback on child's scope, you're not saving data as OP asked "I am trying to save child-data in the state of the parent"